# While loop in SPD with Person/group column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

With SPD i want that my workflow goes to the next step only if the column Person/group is not empty. that's why i have used a while loop and 've created a variable:Person to check if the people field is not empty. My problem now is that the variable:Person take only the first value of the people field which is empty at first So that my Workflow never goes to the next step.

I hope this Image make the situation clear (sorry if it's in french):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by replacing the `loop` with and `if`, which checks

```
if the [variable:Person] is [empty]
    [then] [wait for field change in current item]
```

That's the pseudocode, but should give you the logic. This logic requires the "Start workflow automatically when and item is changed" setting to be enabled.

Comment: I'm working with SPD 2013 is "wait fo field change in current item" still available.

Comment: Can't confirm myself right now, but based on [this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/understanding-eventing-actions-in-sharepoint-designer), it should be there.

Comment: thanks for your response. In fact the option "wait fo field change in current item" is available only if i choose  SharePoint 2010 WF Platform in SPD 2013.

Comment: @HajerFathallah you are probably right. Building and executing SP2010-based WFs should be SP 2013 perfectly viable and supported.